# Difference between real and complex impulse responses?

Tags: impulse-response

I want to know the characteristic differences between real and complex impulse responses.

Thanks, JK

Answer (score 4):

Your question might be the result of a misunderstanding. There is only one type of impulse response, and this is a system's response to a Dirac impulse $\delta(t)$ (in continuous time), or - in discrete time - to a discrete impulse $\delta(n)$. For a real-valued system, i.e. a system with real-valued parameters, the impulse response is always real-valued. For a complex-valued system, i.e. a system with complex-valued parameters (e.g. complex-valued filter coefficients), the impulse response is complex-valued. Note, however, that complex-valued systems are just a convenient way to describe certain real systems, just like complex numbers are often more convenient to establish certain mathematical results.

Comment: L I know that a signal is represented in IQ notation say for calculating the instantaneous phase. But why would an impulse response be represented in such a notation? Can you give me one good situation where such a notation in the context of an impulse-response is preferred?

Comment: @GJK:Taking up your example, you can describe band-pass signals as complex base-band signals (using I and Q components), and - not needing to bother with demodulation - you can describe a receiver structure in the complex domain. And of course the first thing you do to a received signal is filtering, in this case with a complex-valued impulse response.

Comment: "The three things that all electrical engineers must know are Maxwell's equations, Fourier transforms, and complex baseband notation." R. E. Blahut, former Head of the Department of ELectrical and Computer Engineering of the University of Illinois at Urbana-Champaign.

Comment: @MattL. Take digital-up conversion system. Say QPSK modulated signal is given as input this system which up-converts to some RF by complex mixing it with $e^(jwt)$. Now, for transmission we give the real part of the complex mixed output to the DAC. At Rx, we filter and convert this real signal in to complex signals using quadrature filter pair. Even after the conversion, if one wants to filter this complex pair, one can use the same real filter coefficients for I and Q path separately for further signal processing say decimating. This is again brought back to baseband using a complex mixer.